# How do I query update a spreadsheet without using Visualization API, Bigquery or Google Cloud Database?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet that has 4 columns. Column 1 is the "**Timestamp**". Column 2 is "**Volunteer ID Number**". Column 3 is "**Checkin Time**". Column 4 is "**Checkout Time**" and column 5 is "**Total Hours**", which is the total number of hours worked for that day.

The form that is linked to this spreadsheet has a text field for the volunteer's ID number and a multiple choice question asking: "Are you checking in or out?". The volunteer selects between two choices which are "Checkin" or "Checkout". The choices are implemented as a set of radio button choices.

Here are the tasks I want to perform:

1. Split the timestamp string to get the time at which the clock in/out form was submitted.
2. If the volunteer chose "Checkin" on the form, then simply update the cell located at the "Checkin time" column of the last row on the sheet to the time value obtained from the timestamp.
3. If the volunteer chose "Checkout", then delete the last row that google automatically adds to the sheet and then search the sheet for the row in which the "Volunteer ID Number" column  matches the one provided in the form and which is associated with the current date and then set the value of the cell in the "Checkout time" column to the time extracted from the timestamp output. Then, calculate the total number of hours worked by subtracting the time value in the Checkout Time column with the Checkin Time column and then set that number of hours as the value to the Total Hours worked column.

So far, I have been able to accomplish tasks 1 and 2, but I am stuck at task 3.  I can't find a way to do this within Google app scripts effeciently. I'm sure you can gather up all of the rows with in the sheet and then inspect each row for the current date to determine which row that cell is in and then for each of those rows determine if the volunteer ID number from the form matches with the one in the row. I can then update the Checkout Time column in that row, but this would be a very inefficient and slow as the number of rows in the sheet is expected go above 300,000 very quickly.  I looked into Google Visualization API but it does not have an Update or Set clause. There is no way to accomplish what I want to do with the Visualization API.  I know there are database options such as BigQuery and Google Cloud Database querying options, but that costs money and my employer does not want to pay any money for anything. They want this to be a cost free implementation. My employer is a very small non-profit organization that has about 200 volunteers.

Can anyone suggest a method to do this efficiently without having to pay for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest you take a look at my [CheckItOut google forms add-on](https://sites.google.com/site/edlistenscripts/checkitout).  I am working on reporting.
2. If you want to use an actual query, here is a formula I also use for a Check-in/out form that I was using before I wrote CheckItOut.

1st I created a calculations sheet.   On this sheet I listed each item that there is to check out, then used the following formula to find out the last time it was checked in or out.   Column A is a list of the items being checked out.

```
=query('Form Responses 1'!A:E, "Select B,A where D='Check out a Chromebook' and E = '"&$A2&"' order by A desc limit 1",0)
```

I added a column that looks to at the out/in timestamps and depending on which one is greater it will show out vs in.  `=if(C2<D2,"In","Out")`

I then created a 2nd sheet that queried the calculations data to show only the items that are checked out.

```
=query(Calculations!A:E, "Select A,B,C Where E ='Out'")
```